# Overriding base class functions in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

When extending a resource class (following boto3 extensibility guide instructions), there is no inheritance relationship between the base class and the custom class. It results in a base class enriched with the functions and attributes of the custom class.

I was hoping that I would be able to override base class functions, something like:

```py
def create_tags(self, data):
    tags = [{'Key': k.capitalize(), 'Value': v} for k, v in data.items()]
    super().create_tags(Tags=tags)
```

Is there a proper way to achieve this with boto3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not. Boto3 functions are generated on the fly from service definitions, so there is no static `create_tags` function for you to inherit from. Therefore, taking advantage of the [events system](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/events.html) is the only way to extend the functionality of boto3.